# Overwrite tkinter 'ctrl+v' to split the pasting between multiple entries instead of pasting it all in one

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
self.mrEntry.event_delete('<<Paste>>', '<Control-v>')
self.mrEntry.event_add('<Control-v>', lambda *_: self.handle_clipboard()) # ERROR occurs

def handle_clipboard(self):
    # Split the clipboard text up by every '\n' and distribute them among the entries
    # In contrast to pasting all the text into one entry
```

Is it possible to overwrite the `Control-v` shortcut, to distribute the clipboard among multiple entries, in contrast to pasting everything into one single entry?

Starting from the entry that is focused, for every `\n` in the clipboard, paste it into the subsequent entry.

Function responsible for the clipboard handling: (It pastes the text twice, since we got a global bind to paste, and a explicitly made bind to some chosen entries.)

```py
def handle_clipboard(self, focused_entry):
    """Function to destribute the clipboard data into seperate entries"""

    if '\n' not in root.clipboard_get():
        # If there is only one line in clipboard, paste it all in the focused cell
        return

    # count number of lines (cells) there is in the clipboard
    clipboard_cells = (cell for line in root.clipboard_get().split('\n')[:-1]
                                for cell in line.split('\t'))
    print(clipboard_cells)

    # Find corresponding 'key' for the 'focused entry'
    for key, entry in self.entries.items():
        if entry == focused_entry:
            break

    # We start from the focused cell and insert until there are no more entries
    index = self.nøgletal.index(key)
    for entry in (self.entries[entry] for entry in self.nøgletal[index:]):

        try:
            n = next(clipboard_cells)
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert(0, n)
        except StopIteration:
            # There is not more to paste
            # but still more entries to paste in
            pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea usability-wise, but the implementation is pretty simple. You don't have to use `event_delete` or `event_add`, you just need to bind to the `<<Paste>>` event.

If you bind to the special catch-all `"all"`, you only have to do a single binding that will work no matter which widget has the focus, though you could instead bind only to the entry widgets if you want.

The important thing is to have your function return the string `"break"` which prevents any other event handler from handling the paste event.

Here's a contrived example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(height=6)
text.pack(side="top", fill="x")

for i in range(10):
    text.insert("end", "this is line #%d\n" % i)

entrys = []
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    entrys.append(entry)

def handle_clipboard(event):
    for entry in entrys:
        entry.delete(0, "end")

    lines = root.clipboard_get().split("\n")
    for entry, line in zip(entrys, lines):
        entry.insert(0, line)
    return "break"

root.bind_all("<<Paste>>", handle_clipboard)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I need to only have a few entries binded with this overwritten version of ctrl+v. With the help of your code I managed to make it work with a tiny issue. It pastes the text twice in the first cell. I think that tkinter does the global binding paste command, and afterwards the specific binding for the entry I made, resulting in my text being pasted twice in the first entry. 

How can I resolve this issue? I have to somehow unbind the global (or at least overwrite) 'paste' from the specific entries I choose to bind.

Comment: @Bjango: you forgot to return the string `"break"`, which is what prevents the default binding from pasting.